# what does signal "resource-request-starting" do in webkitgtk?

Tags: webkit, gtk

I am a beginner in webkitgtk. I would like to know the functioning of the signal "resource-request-starting". I have gone through the [manual-page](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-resource-request-starting) but I didnt get enough information. What is the use of this signal in webkitgtk?

Answer (score 1):

When the web page tries to load something through a URI, the signal is emitted, in case you want to modify the load request.

This signal was generally used to implement custom URI schemes. (In WebKit2, there is a better way to do that.)